# Datastax Spark Cassandra Connector. How to set the version for a custom build?

Tags: cassandra, sbt, spark-cassandra-connector

I build a custom patched version of Datastax Spark Cassandra Connector for Scala 2.11. I failed to find where its version "2.0.0-M3" is coming from.

I tried

> grep -lr "2.0.0-M3" *

and everything it has found were under "*/target/*" or in *.md files, - no "build.sbt", "build.properties", etc.

Does anyone know how to set the version?
I need to use the custom version in my project.

Answer (score 1):

The version is set in project/Settings.scala:

`def currentVersion = ("git describe --tags --match v*" !!).trim.substring(1)`

To set custom one use:

`git tag -a vYourVersionHere`